# How to do a where() on any column in model

Tags: laravel

I have four columns that I want to do a `LIKE` query on, `user_id`,`client_id`, and  `start_time`, and `end_time`

I have the current statement

```
Model::where('client_id','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
```

However, instead of it being `client_id`, I'd like to be able to search through all four of those columns rather then just one, without using a `whereOr` as that does not work efficiently for my problem
Thank you in advance.

Comment: please provide more details, and your current code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use where and Search records

```
$user_id = $request->user_id ? '%' . $request->user_id . '%' : '';
$client_id = $request->client_id ? '%' . $request->client_id . '%' : '';

$modal = Modal::where(function($q) use($user_id, $client_id) { 
             $q->where("user_id", "like", "$user_id")
               ->orwhere("client_id", "like", "$client_id");})->get();

 dump($modal->count()); // count display
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You may do like this below.

```
  Model::where(function($q) { 
         $q->where('user_id','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
          ->orWhere('client_id','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
          ->orWhere('start_time','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')
          ->orWhere('end_time','LIKE','%'.$q.'%');
    });
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Erwin Saurez Sorry for the late response, it did not yield any results searching, the code in the answer above worked very well for my solution, however thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use when and filter if you have setted one or another variable:

```
Model::when(isset($client_id),function($query) use ($client_id) { 
        $query->where('client_id','=', $client_id)
     })
     ->when(isset($user_id),function($query) use ($user_id) { 
        $query->where('user_id','=', $user_id)
     })
     ->when(isset($start_time),function($query) use ($start_time) {
        $query->where('start_time','=',$start_time)
     })
     ->get();
```